# Creating polygons with fixed extent based on point which represents S/W corner using QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, polyline-creation

I have a point data set which contains the information of workplaces per hectare.

Each point represents the South-Western corner of the surveyed hectare. Not the entire map is covered with points, only there where people are working does a point even exist.

I want to create now a polygon shapefile with many rectangular polygons (100*100m) and the information from the point.

In the image you can see how the point relates to the desired polygons. The ones scribbled in black are not necessary, as there are no workspaces.

I am using QGIS.

[image: example]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In QGIS, use "Geometry by Expression" tool (in a projected CRS). It will also add points information/attributes to polygons.

- Select "Polygon" as "Output geometry type" option.
- Add the following expression as "Geometry expression" value:

  ```
  make_square(make_point($x, $y), make_point($x+100, $y+100))
  ```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Using a Virtual layer, you can create a polygon of the desired dimension and move it to each location of the point layer. You can then `save as` the output if you want to persist the data.

Go to the menu `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...` and enter the following query. Replace the layer name for yours.

```sql
WITH src AS (
SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 0, 100 0, 100 100, 0 100, 0 0))') AS geometry
)

SELECT ID, ST_Translate(src.geometry, st_x(pt.geometry), st_y(pt.geometry),0) as geometry
FROM "myPointLayer" pt, src
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For each point (x,y) in a projected CRS generate a string like:

```
polygon((x y, x+100, y, x+100, y+100, x y+100, x y))
```

you can then process that into a `Polygon` using `geom_from_wkt`.

Then save the layer as a shapefile (or better still a GeoPackage).

Comment: thank you for your answer. Sorry for asking, but where you write that code?

Comment: in the field calculator when you add your new field